# Can In install gravel over old asphalt for a shed base?

Tags: shed, driveway, gravel

Where I want to put our new shed (16x24) there used to be an asphalt pad the previous owners used for parking. I'd prefer to not rip that up and instead just level gravel on top of it but I'm worried about drainage. Is it okay to go right on top of the this asphalt or should I remove it all?

Comment: Does water pool on the asphalt pad now?

Comment: There is minimal friction between gravel and asphalt surface. If you are in a windy area, expect the shed to slide sideway.

Comment: Why not just use the existing concrete driveway as the pad for the shed?  Not much different than pouring a dedicated pad of the appropriate thickness for a shed.

Comment: there's lots of kinds of "gravel", some drain, and some don't, so use what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Gravel doesn't hold water so if the old asphalt drained okay I wouldn't anticipate any problem.

I'm a bit puzzled why the shed can't sit on the old asphalt and the gravel run around it to hide any asphalt still seen.

Comment: It's sloped and I'd prefer the new pad to be level

Comment: Ah, got you... I hope it's stable in the gravel though. Alternative is to use impregnated timber 'packers', or other material like paving slabs etc.